# PrometheusReportingTask not emitting metrics in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, prometheus

I created a new PrometheusReportingTask using the hamburger menu and then chose "All Components" strategy, as show below:

[image]

In the Settings, Run Schedule is set to "60 sec"

As you can see below the PrometheusReportingTask is running.

Also confirmed this in the nifi log file:

```
 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server jetty-9.4.26.v20200117; built: 2020-01-17T12:35:33.676Z; git: 7b38981d25d14afb4a12ff1f2596756144edf695; jvm 11.0.5+10-LTS
 INFO o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a6d7945{/metrics,null,AVAILABLE}
 INFO o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@139a9c85{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9092}
 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @16382501ms
 INFO o.a.n.r.p.PrometheusReportingTask PrometheusReportingTask[id=1b3385ce-0174-1000-ff14-1bf8d240953c] Started JETTY server
 INFO o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent PrometheusReportingTask[id=1b3385ce-0174-1000-ff14-1bf8d240953c] started.
```

[image]

I have a processor group Foo Group and I was expecting to see the JVM as well as this processor group metrics

[image]

However when I cURL the metrics endpoint, I don't find any metrics. There is no error, just no output.

```
$curl localhost:9092/metrics
$
```

Also, when I stop the PrometheusReportingTask, I do see the metrics endpoint become unavailable

```
 $curl localhost:9092/metrics
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9092: Connection refused
```

Is there something else that needs to be configured?

I am using Apache NiFi 1.10.0, and I tried this on 1.12.0 both with no success.  Which tells me, there is something I am missing in the configuration or I am not hitting the endpoint correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trailing slash is required when pulling from the metrics endpoint:

```
curl localhost:9092/metrics/
```

Comment: We are trying to configure prometheus .do we need to configure endpoint with '/' in end in prometheus too path too?

Comment: That is absurd.  But thank you!